# Processing XML file where tag data may contain processing instructions

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, processing-instruction

I am using python to extract the coordinate data from an non-standard xml file.
The issue is that some of the `coordinates` tags contain xml processing instructions, for example

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml>
    <Document>
        <Folder>
            <Placemark id="CAR1">
            <coordinates>
                28.236931382585154893,36.380279408060658852,200<?AtTime 0.000000?>
                28.236862947306430982,36.380324400967296583,200<?AtTime 2.333333?>
                28.236862521767100986,36.380323843439811071,200<?AtTime 2.500000?>
            </coordinates>
                </Placemark>
        <Placemark id="CAR2">
            <coordinates>
                28.236931382585154893,36.380279408060658852,200
                28.236862947306430982,36.380324400967296583,200
                28.236862521767100986,36.380323843439811071,200
            </coordinates>
        </Placemark>
       </Folder>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Below is my test code

```python
from xml.dom import minidom
myFile = "test.xml"
mydoc = minidom.parse(myFile)
items = mydoc.getElementsByTagName('Placemark')
for elem in items:
    print("coordinates ",elem.attributes['id'].value)
    coorTag = elem.getElementsByTagName('coordinates')
    if len(coorTag) > 0:
        for elem in coorTag:
            theData = elem.firstChild.nodeValue
            print(theData)
```

This generates the following output.

```
coordinates  CAR1

                28.236931382585154893,36.380279408060658852,200
coordinates  CAR2

                28.236931382585154893,36.380279408060658852,200
                28.236862947306430982,36.380324400967296583,200
                28.236862521767100986,36.380323843439811071,200
```

How can I obtain all the coordinate data even when the internal data of a given tag may contain processing instructions? 
Is this just a problem with minidom, maybe an alternative python library would be better?

The output I am looking for is.

```
coordinates  CAR1

                28.236931382585154893,36.380279408060658852,200<?AtTime 0.000000?>
                28.236862947306430982,36.380324400967296583,200<?AtTime 2.333333?>
                28.236862521767100986,36.380323843439811071,200<?AtTime 2.500000?>
coordinates  CAR2

                28.236931382585154893,36.380279408060658852,200
                28.236862947306430982,36.380324400967296583,200
                28.236862521767100986,36.380323843439811071,200
```

Comment: I feel the most flexible approach would be to extract all the data from the coordinate tag's data including the processes instructions. This would then give the option to process the data in whatever way is necessary,

Comment: It is unusual to see processing instructions interspersed with text like that, but there isn't really anything "non-standard" about it. Please edit the question to show the exact wanted output. What does "process the data in whatever way is necessary" mean?

Comment: Have updated the question to provide a required output. As for "process the data in whatever way is necessary", I intend to extract all the values, including the AtTime values in the process statement, and then generate a revised "more" conforming XML/KML file, however that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Have now tried with ElementTree and lxml.etree. ElementTree extracts all the data correctly, since it ignores any processing instructions.  lxml.etree has the same problem as minidom, but does provide the ability to extract the processing instructions associated with a coordinates tag.